# XAMPP for windows 64-bit machine

Tags: xampp

I want to download XAMPP for my windows 64-bit machine. But officially, XAMPP is only available for a 32-bit windows machine.

So, is it fine if I use 32-bit windows XAMPP version for my 64-bit windows machine or is there a way to get the 64-bit windows XAMPP version?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: you can simple try it.

Comment: I don't understand why you use xampp instead of wamp.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's fine.

A 32 bit build will run fine on 64 bit Windows.

Php and Apache don't have official supported 64 bit Windows builds, only MySql out of the three does, hence no 64 bit bundle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also want to know whether running a 32-bit windows XAMPP on a 64-bit windows machine makes a difference. If so, in what way?

Comment: Certain circumstances require 64 bit - so 'just run 32 bit' is not a useful answer.

Comment: and no official one?

Answer (score 2):

it possible to run 32 bit XAMPP on 64bit machine. it is all fine, so far there is no 64 bit XAMPP application. personally I use 32 bit XAMPP server on 64bit windows 10 machine. it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Yes, XAMPP will run and install on a 32-bit Windows.

No, because if you want to maximize XAMPP's use of RAM, your OS will run out of that same RAM. Hence, it may make sense to host it on a 64-bit Windows, say allocate it with 6gb of RAM for OS and other uses.

Answer (score 0):

**is it fine if I use 32-bit windows XAMPP version for my 64-bit windows machine**

**Yes**! I have just downloaded 32-bit XAMPP version for windows-10, because I have not got version for 64-bit windows-10, It works fine for the applications. I am running framework known as Laravel and Codeigniter for developing php web applications. There is no any issue.

**is there a way to get the 64-bit windows XAMPP version?**

**No** ! As per my experience-- I have not got 64-bit XAMPP for windows-10.

**Conclusion** - You can download 32-bit XAMPP version for windows-10 and can use it without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issues you may run into on windows using 32bit PHP (as all parts of XAMPP will be 32bit) is with any numbers larger than 32bit

For instance the ip2long() functions will return negative numbers instead of positive integers for some larger computed IP addresses.